# Kraken.js set maxAge for static files

Tags: node.js, express, kraken.js

I'm trying to set the max-age for static files using Kraken.js (Express.js/Node.js)

I use to edit `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneDay })` to set this, but it looks like it is not available anymore.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `maxAge` option is [still available](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/7a2f3c6ca8c91ee8cb7dc74a27d01b788c2ed5a7/Readme.md#servestaticroot-options) in express' `static` middleware.

Assuming you're using kraken >= v1.0, serving static assets is [handled for you](https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-js/blob/4ae1cc4d88d7be6ff4f81a25ed718ea8df21fa1e/config/config.json#L51-L58) by default. I cannot be certain without looking at your code but it's highly likely your `app.use(express.static ...` isn't actually doing anything since, again, kraken defaults to serving up your static assets for you. Try removing it and seeing if your static assets are still being served up.

If that's the case, you'll want to set the `maxAge` config inside your `config/config.json` (or `config/development.json` if you want to have a different value in development).

This is what that would look like in your config (`864e5` being the number of ms in a day):

```
{
    "middleware": {
        "static": {
            "module": {
                "name": "serve-static",
                "arguments": [
                    "path:./public",
                    { "maxAge": 864e5 }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. Finally I edited config/config.json file with: "middleware":{"static": {"module": {"arguments": [ "path:./.build" , {"maxAge" : 60000}]}}, ...